# batch file to get file name up to specified character

Tags: batch-file

I have filenames in a directory in the format of `Mumbai Short Call Agentwise-MUMBAI SHORT CALL-3-01092016`.  I would like to strip off everything after the second hyphen and keep the first portion of the filename.

Is there a good website that could direct me in how to accomplish this?  Or, maybe one of you dos batch experts can lead me in how to do this?

Comment: I suggest you remove the part asking for a good web site and focus on help on the actual problem from the community. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,* delims=-" %%a in ('dir /b *-*-*') do @ECHO ren "%%a-%%b-%%c" "%%a-%%b%%~xc"
```

for every file with the given mask `*-*.*`: get first (`%%a`) and second part (`%%b`) plus extension of the rest (rest: `%%c`; Extension of the rest:`%%~xc`)

Notes:
- if you shorten filenames, be aware of possible duplicates!
`@ECHO` just *lists* the rename commands. Remove `@ECHO`, if the output satisfies you

See `for /?` or  [for /f](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) for more information

Comment: if my files are in D:\NewFolder then what changes should be done in this – for /f "tokens=1,2,* delims=-" %%a in ('dir /b *-*-*') do @ECHO ren "%%a-%%b-%%c" "%%a-%%b%%~xc"

Comment: easiest way: `cd /d "d:\NewFolder"` before. Better way: `pushd "d:\NewFolder"` before and `popd` after.